# html table exported as xlsx but excel 2013 can't open it

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-table, xlsx

This is my function that turns my html table into an excel file. The problem is, I need to save that excel file as .xlsx but I couldn't do it. Are there anybody to help?

```
function exceller() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;content-disposition:attachment;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

    $('#toExcel').html($('#pztable').html());
    var toExcel = $('#toExcel').html();
    var ctx = {
        worksheet: name || '',
        table: toExcel
    };
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "export.xlsx";
    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    link.click();
    link.remove();
}
```

Here is jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jxz60kqj/

Comment: I didn't read carefully enough.  Why are you trying to manually click that link?

Comment: Also can you provide a fiddle of your work?

Comment: It is an angular project and my data of table is so complicated. But I'm gonna try to export it to the jsfiddle. I tried window location function too. It didnt worked too..  @TMB

Comment: I am worried about those last two lines, why are they necessary?  In my answer below the user has to click the link for it to download.

Comment: It just doesnt matter. you can delete last 5 lines and add this,

window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx)) + '.xlsx';

it is the same thing but it just doesn't work...

Comment: Why don't you start with my working example and slowly/iteratively build it up to your example and see where it breaks.

Comment: I added jsFiddle :) Thank you so much for your all help...

Comment: It opened for me.  Though, I was using libre office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using third-party jQuery plugins? I've been using `jquery.table2excel.js` and it worked fine.

You need to include the JQuery plugin and the Table2Excel plugin which can be found [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel).

Code:

```
$("button").click(function(){ 
   $("#table2excel").table2excel({ 
      // exclude CSS class 
      exclude: ".noExl", 
      name: "Worksheet Name", 
      filename: "SomeFile" //do not include extension 
   }); 
 });
```

Demo here:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I dont want to use a plugin for this kind of thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tbeckenhauer/mueqr96t/9/

If you set the href and a download attribute you can download it

HTML

```
<a id="link" href="" download='blah.txt'>Download File!</a>
```

JavaScript

```
var excelData = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent('your data goes here');

$('#link').click(function(event) {
    $(event.target).attr('href', excelData);
});
```

Comment: The problem is not the download the file. the problem is when I download the file it is not openable with excel 2013. I already doing something like you said :) But thank you for your answer

Comment: I understand now, excel doesn't open the file.

Comment: I am going to recommend you change the title to a question, that states that clearly.  It will help attract the right people to answer this question.  "Why won't excel open this file?"

Comment: Sorry my mistake :) You are right. I'm gonna change it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I was creating just an **html table** with **'xls formatted head Element'** to can be read truly by **Excel** but **xlsx** just a different type of format for that kind of datas. It is packaged of many of **xml** actually. So there is nothing to make an **html table** export as xlsx. I used '**ALASQL**' to do that. It worked awesome. I **recommend** to you to use '**ALASQL**' to solve that problem.